# IE bad rendering for anchor element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having some trouble with the anchor element rendering in IE (IE9 in my case).
If you look at the image linked below, you can notice a sort of bad padding or bad positioning for the second element.  In similar questions I found `a { display: inline-block }` as a solution, but it seems it doesn't work for me.
However I noticed that playing with some CSS property like `clear` or `height` or others, apparently without any logic, rendering may be correct.
Thanks!

[image: IE9 Bad Rendering]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>
            body {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
            a {height:13px;}
            p {clear:both; float:left;}
            .link {clear:both; float:left; border:1px solid #00f; background-color:#0f0;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <a class="link" href="my_page.html">ABCDEF</a>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <a class="link" href="my_page.html">ABCDEF</a>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <a class="link" href="my_page.html">ABCDEF</a>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <a class="link" href="my_page.html">ABCDEF</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image looks OK for me. Using `<p>` is generating the 'padding' I see. If you want no space between lines then put everything inside the same `<p>` tag.

```
    ...
    <p>
    TEXT<br />
    <a class="link" href="my_page.html">ABCDEF</a></ br>
    TEXT<br />
    <a class="link" href="my_page.html">ABCDEF</a></ br>
    TEXT<br />
    <a class="link" href="my_page.html">ABCDEF</a></ br>
    TEXT<br />
    <a class="link" href="my_page.html">ABCDEF</a>
    </p>
    ...
```

But I would rather use lists to display that kind of data

Comment: Thanks, but I have some other example where only divs and anchors are used, and the 'padding' problem is the same. There isn't a more general way to correct it?

Comment: Run this on IE9 (http://jsfiddle.net/JHzbs/) look at the second element again, there is 1px missing padding...

Comment: It's not just IE9, I see the same padding issue with Chrome and other browsers. You are specifying a fixed height for the square (13px) while the anchor takes more than that (and may vary according to the browser's different fonts). You are tied to that layout using only divs? 
http://jsfiddle.net/tnWgt/
Is that approach better?

Answer (score 0):

New version: look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/yAumT/11/